# Get differences between consecutive elements of the array (like R diff() function)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there an more elegant way than that below of mapping differences between array elements of `[5,3,4,4,5]` to `[-2,1,0,1]` in javascript--analogous to R, where you can easily get the differences between array elements `x=c(5,3,4,4,5)` with `diff(x)` giving you `(-2,1,0,1)`?

```js
let test = [5, 3, 4, 4, 5]
console.log(test.map((x, i) => {
  if (i < test.length - 1) return test[i] - test[i + 1]
  else return null
}).filter(x => x != null))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could slice the array from index 1 and map the delat of the same index of the given and sliced array.

```js
const diff = array => array.slice(1).map((v, i) => v - array[i]);

console.log(diff([5, 3, 4, 4, 5])); // [-2, 1, 0, 1]
```